# WooCommerce product has 'product image' but no 'featured image'

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 2.1.3 with a custom theme.  The custom theme grabs the 'featured image' from pages and used it to stretch and display a header image (some jQuery stuff).  Point is, WooCommerce uses 'product image' and not 'featured image'.  I am assuming this is why my theme is not picking up the photo and using it for the header image.... the header remains blank.  Anyway to add this 'featured image' back in to products?  This way, they have similar attributed to regular pages.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

This is the PHP file that contains the jQuery as well.  The file is called page-title-progression.php

```
<?php if(is_404() ): ?>
    <div id="page-title">
        <div class="width-container paged-title">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( '404 Page Not Found ', 'progression' ); ?></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
    </div><!-- #page-title -->
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
        <script type='text/javascript'>

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
            $("#page-title").backstretch([
                "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                    if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                        echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                    }

                    if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                        echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ],{
                    fade: 750,
                    duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
             });
        });

        </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>

    <?php if(is_page()): ?>
        <?php
        global $wp_query;
        $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
        ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_home() || is_single() && 'portfolio' != get_post_type() && 'menu' != get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo get_the_title($page_for_posts); ?></h1>
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_archive() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                    <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'F Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Archives: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( is_tag() ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            printf( __( 'Tag: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . single_tag_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ( is_author() ) : ?>
                        <?php _e( 'Author Archives:', 'progression' ); ?>
                        <?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
                              echo '' . $user_info->display_name . "\n";
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if(post_type_exists('menu') ) : ?>
                        <?php
                            printf( __( '%s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_search() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search for: %s', 'progression' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1></div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>

        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(is_single() && 'portfolio' == get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>



    <?php if(is_single() && 'menu' == get_post_type() ): ?>
        <div id="page-title">
            <div class="width-container paged-title">
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>  
            </div>
        <div id="page-title-divider"></div>
        </div><!-- #page-title -->
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts'); ?>
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail($page_for_posts)): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($page_for_posts), 'progression-page-title'); ?>
            <script type='text/javascript'>

            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
                $("#page-title").backstretch([
                    "<?php echo $image[0]; ?>"
                    <?php if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-2', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }

                        if( kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) != "" ) {
                            echo ',"', kd_mfi_get_featured_image_url( 'featured-image-3', 'page', 'progression-page-title', $thePostID ) , '"';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],{
                        fade: 750,
                        duration: <?php echo of_get_option('slider_autoplay', 8000); ?>
                 });
            });

            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: WooCommerce still uses featured images and just changes the text in the interface to "product image." Can you post query code you are using?

Comment: I added the code above.  It works everywhere else but on product pages.  I even tried copying over PHP code from a template that I know works (to the single-product page, this is the page template that woocommerce uses to display single products) and it still would not display the header image.  This is driving me nuts.  Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming I need to add a new if statement that recognizes product pages.  This is just a guess.  Thoughts?  If this is indeed correct then perhaps you may know how to make the if call?

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to create a new if statement for product pages:  `<?php if(is_product()): ?>`